# strncpy behaviour in different IDEs

Tags: c, string, memory, malloc

I am wondering why in Eclipse with internal CDT builder I can do this

```
char *data = 0;
char data2[20] = "Hello";

strncpy(data, data2, 10);
```

But in visual studio I have to do this

```
char *data = malloc(20);
char data2[20] = "Hello";

strncpy(data, data2, 10);
```

As you can see I have to use `malloc()` in visual studio otherwise I get access violation to memory, but why don't I need it in eclipse?

Comment: The first snippet leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). End of story.

Comment: Im sorry but I really didnt. If I wouldve known i wouldnt have asked...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It would be more helpful to explain why this is UB, as was done in the answer below.

Comment: It's still strange that it doesn't segfault with CDT.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I assume the implementor of the library function is free to check for `NULL` and do nothing instead of initiating official "crash&burn" sequence. Just for your convenience. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh maybe, but I've never seen such an implementation and I doubt that this would be a convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *most* of the cases,

```
  char *data = 0;
```

is the same as

```
  char *data = NULL;
```

and then, you're using a `NULL` pointer (i.e., an *invalid* address you're not suppose to *access*) as a target for `strncpy()`. It is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Elaborated in `C11`, chapter §7.1.4, *Use of library functions*

> [....] **If an argument to a function has an invalid value** (such as a value
>   outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program,
>   or **a null pointer**, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding
>   parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function
>   with variable number of arguments, **the behavior is undefined.** [...]

Comment: Even if it's technically UB, it's still strange that it doesn't segfault with CDT.

Comment: @MichaelWalz well, of all people, you know it very well sir, the _beautiful_ side of UB. :)